# API 400 error Username required Password required

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net, api

I am sending JSON data to external API as following :

```
Dim url = "https://********"
    Dim _httpClient = New HttpClient()
    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = New AuthenticationHeaderValue("MyUsername", "MyPassword")

    Using content = New StringContent(json, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
        Dim result As HttpResponseMessage = _httpClient.PostAsync(url, content).Result
                    If result.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created Then
            Console.WriteLine(result.StatusCode)
            Return True
        End If
```

but I am receiving the following error:

> {"status":400,"message":"Invalid Request","data":[{"field":"username","message":"Username required"},{"field":"password","message":"Password required"}]}

how to fix this issue ?

Comment: looks like your api expects username and password in the body but you.are sending inside header.check api definition

Comment: should I define the username and password as parameters in the body ?

Comment: it depends on your api design.

Comment: here is the API definition: 

https://doc.e-faa.com.sa/#404f45da-e919-425a-92e2-77b88a4c0ebf

POSTUpload Simple Invoice

Comment: as per you API definition, it is supposed to added as simple header value as key value pair. not in body. not in authorization header.

Comment: what should I add to the code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your API definition it is expecting username and password in the header as key value pair. you can add them like this.

```
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Username", "MyUsername");
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("password", "MyPassword");
```

Comment: That's work perfectly.

Now how to get the exact data through the result 
( "{""status"":200,""message"":""Operation Done Successfully"",""data"":{""billNumber"":""0006"",""sadadNumber"":""220880019""}}")
for example : (( ""sadadNumber"":""220880019""} )) ??